# What is the best way to send variable values bidirectionally from .KV file to python?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, slider

What would be the best practice for sending and receiving data from a KV file to python? Tring to make a simple program that changes the color of a object with three faders. I wish to set a initial base value of where the sliders and colors the sliders will control will start at when the program is first ran. I then would Like to be able to take slider value and use the values in other parts of the project after, ether for displaying the values in other text box or whatever.

I do intend to have a serial or network control added to this project. Basically I would like to have multiple instances of the program running and a slider movement value of one instance to control another. Implementing this is out of the scope of this current phase of the project but if there is some extra steps to connect the values of the sliders to other chunks of code to implement such a feature. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Here's what I have so far I'm stuck on line 6 in the .py. I'm not sure how to take the 3 slider values and feed them into the text box color value. While being able to display the values in other parts of the program such as a print statement or another text box.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class MyLayout(GridLayout):
    def slide(self):
        self.ids["lable"].color = red,green,blue,1
        print(self.ids["red"].value)


class slider(App):

    def build(self):

        return MyLayout()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = slider()
    window.run()
```

.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<MyLayout>

    cols:2

    Slider:
        id: red
        min:0
        max:1
        #on_value:label.text = str(int(self.value))
        on_value: root.slide()


    Slider:
        id: green
        min:0
        max:1
        #on_value:label.text = str(int(self.value))
        on_value: root.slide()

    Slider:
        id: blue
        min:0
        max:1
        #on_value:label.text = str(int(self.value))
        on_value: root.slide()

    Label:
        id:label
        text:"0"
```

All the code you see is code I have pieced together from tutorials I have found, so if I'm going about this the wrong way its because I don't understand Kivy or python yet. Most tutorials assume you know python well and have a firm understanding of object oriented programing .

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the color of the `Label` in your `slide()` method:

```
def slide(self):
    self.ids["label"].color = self.ids.red.value, self.ids.green.value, self.ids.blue.value, 1
    print(self.ids["red"].value)
```

And if you want to display the color in the `Label`:

```
Label:
    id:label
    color: 1, 0.5, 0.75, 1  # initial color
    text: str(round(self.color[0], 2)) + ', ' + str(round(self.color[1], 2)) + ', ' + str(round(self.color[2], 2))
```